# How to access DOJO files from local copy?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have downloaded DOJO and I am keeping it in my local folder. In the download files "dojo.xd.js" file not found and when I try the below code, dojo is not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:\dojo\dojo\dojo.js">  </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:\dojo\dijit\form\Button.js">  </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:\dojo\dijit\Dialog.js">   </script>
```

But when I use the below code, it is working.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://o.aolcdn.com/dojo/1.1.1/dojo/dojo.xd.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad: true"> </script>
```

How to access DOJO from the local drive? Help me

Answer (score 2):

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/quickstart/install.html#quickstart-install

When You have directory that looks something like that:

```
|- index.html
|-js/
   |- foo.js
```

In `index.html` You should add:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/foo.js"></script>
```

And then foo.js would be included.